# Does Salesforce support callout using Kerberos authentication?

Tags: callout, authentication

Does Salesforce callout using Kerberos authentication? I cannot find any supporting documentation saying it does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you couldn't find any documentation is because it's not supported. You will need to use a supported protocol such as Basic, OAuth2, or SSL certificates.